# Constructing a Free Body Diagram (Stacked Blocks)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

How can I construct the free body diagram of this figure? I am in a topic of equilibrium of particles so the total force will be equal to zero.
The two springs are indicated to give equal forces.

Am I correct that I will add the masses of the blocks and then I will make now an FBD together with the two spring forces?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a free-body diagram (FBD), you have to decide what the "body" is.

In any physical situation, you can draw many free-body diagrams... some are more useful to answering questions you may have.

Is the "body" the rectangular block L ?
Or is the "body" the "system of F-and-L" ?

Once that is decided, you then ask:
What are all of the pushes and pulls [directly applied by other objects] on that "body"? Those will correspond to external-forces on the  "body".